# Fastes way to Copy big file (50G) from shared directory to local ssd drive in Linux

Tags: linux, unix, copy, rsync, azcopy

What is the best way to copy big files(10G to 50G) files from shared directory to local drive ssd (both are mounted in same machine)

Lets say-machine-01 has below mount point:

/smb/share01/
/root/

copy /smb/share01/50G_file to /root

Linux cp is very slow, I am copying only one file at time(no multiple files copy) in each machine.

is there any tools, that make parallel thread copy and copies much faster like azcopy

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions.

Comment: Would the source speed up with multiple threads or slow down due to seeks?

Comment: @stark, not sure, cp command does not use multi threads